# $modal.open(...) : undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my angular controller, I want to open a modal, and detect when it is closed. Yet the documentation and what I'm seeing don't line up. In particular, when the handler on `'$viewContentLoaded'` is called, I get unexpected results from the `$modal` service object.

This is my current best attempt:

```
controllersModule.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$log','$location', '$modal', 
'$sce', '$q', '$timeout', '$http',
                           function($scope, $log, $location, $modal, $sce, $q, $timeout, $http) {

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function checkBrowserCompatibility(){
    var m = $modal({title: 'You can read this',
                    content: 'This works',
                    show: true,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false}); 
}]);
```

The above produces the modal I expect; however, [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) suggest I should be calling it more like

```
var m = $modal.open({title: 'You cannot read this',
                    content: 'This never shows up',
                    show: true,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false});
```

which gives me the ol' `TypeError: undefined is not a function` at `$modal.open(...)` I'd like to be able to detect when a user closes the modal, though at this time it does not need any more behavior than that--no passing data back from the modal or anything like that. Just pop up a message and move on.

Actually, another acceptable (even desirable) behavior would be preventing the modal from closing at all...

Comment: Im not sure, but your injections do not match? You have not included $sce in your controller?

Comment: See latest edit. That was simply a transcription error. I removed a number of the other injected services, and internal code for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that this issue is probably caused by a mismatch of your Angular js and Angular Bootstrap UI js libraries.

Please note that the latest version of AngularJS Bootstrap UI 0.12.1 requires Angular 1.2.16+

Check your includes and that the versions are compatible.

Comment: It was stupider even than that, though that was looking in the right place. The problem was that the original author of this code employed angular-strap, rather than angular-bootstrap-ui.... so it's just a whole different though similar API.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call it like this:

```
   var m = $modal.open({
            content: 'something',
            controller: modalBootstrap,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
        });

        m.result.then(
            function () {
             //this is called when the modal is closed.
           },
            function () {
             //this is called when the modal is dismissed.
           }
        );
```

You will pass the instance of your modal to the controller inside the modal using the controller property.  We call this a bootstrap controller that looks like this:

```
var modalBootstrap = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.modalInstance = $modalInstance;

};
modalBootstrap['$inject'] = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];
```

Now, inside your modal controller you can close the modal by calling one of these functions:

```
$scope.modalInstance.dismiss();
$scope.modalInstance.close();
```

Each one of these will close the modal and make it's corresponding callback function fire.

The two functions in the m.result will get called depending on if the modal was closed or dismissed.  You can do your work there.

Comment: Doesn't seem like I'm quite following. Where does the `modalBootstrap` declare/define belong? Putting it in the event listener declaration doesn't work, nor does putting it in the controller function body immediately preceding the `$scope.$on ...` assignment. Both of these cases still show the same error. And I don't quite see how that _could_ resolve the issue, given that the problem is occurring at $modal.open, not that modal's controller or other parameters

Comment: We include the modalBootstrap in it's own file and bundle it in with the build.  You just include the file where you include your other controller files.  My answer solves your question about how to tell when the modal is closed.  Please make sure your version of angular and angular bootstrap are compatible. That is probably what is causing error.

Comment: thanks, nweg. Turns out the problem is that the code I inherited is not using angular-bootstrap at all! I may make the switch, though, if I can find time and opportunity for it...

Comment: The switch wouldn't be hard at all and probably save you time down the road.  If you do, take a look at my answer as it may help with your other problem.  Good luck!